# Eigenvalues of a product with more than two factors, with eigenvalues of pairwise products known

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given four real square matrices $M_i$, $i=1,\cdots,4$

We know that the eigenvalues of all $M_i$ have unit norm ($|\lambda|=1$).

We also know that the eigenvalues of any pairwise product $M_i M_j$ have unit norm.

Can we conclude anything about the eigenvalues of $M_1M_2M_3M_4$? In particular, do they have unit norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $$M_2=M_3=M_4=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$ and let $M_1$ be the rotation matrix that takes $[3,1]^T$ to the $y$ axis.

The $M_i$ all have eigenvalues with norm $1$, and clearly so does any product $M_iM_j$ when $i,j>1$, since $$M_iM_j=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ As for [$M_1M_j$](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eig%28%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D*%7B%7Bcos%28arctan%283%29%29%2C-sin%28arctan%283%29%29%7D%2C%7Bsin%28arctan%283%29%29%2Ccos%28arctan%283%29%29%7D%7D%29) and [$M_iM_1$](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eig%28%7B%7Bcos%28arctan%283%29%29%2C-sin%28arctan%283%29%29%7D%2C%7Bsin%28arctan%283%29%29%2Ccos%28arctan%283%29%29%7D%7D%29), they also have only eigenvalues with unit norm. However, we have $$M_1M_2M_3M_4\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\sqrt{10}\end{bmatrix}$$

I don't know how far you can push this technique by increasing the top right element of the $M_i$, $i>1$ (and adjust the rotation accordingly). At some point, the $M_1M_j$ product is going to produce real eigenvalues larger than $1$, I think, but I don't know where.